# « Frapper à la bonne porte » ou « frapper la bonne porte » ?

Tags: expressions, usage, prépositions

Dit-on :

> Frapper à la bonne porte

ou

> Frapper la bonne porte ?

Le **à** me pose problème.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On dit *Frapper **à** la bonne porte*.

Pour le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/)

> **Frapper**, verbe.
>   […]
>   II.− Emploi intrans.
>   A.− [La prép. indique la destination du coup] **Frapper à**, **chez**, **contre**, **sur**. *Frapper sur la table*.
>     ♦ Frapper à la porte ou absol. frapper. Demander à entrer.<sup>[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frapper)</sup>

Autrement dit, il s'agit d'un emploi particulier du verbe *frapper* qui utilise *à* pour désigner un objet sur lequel on frappe. En particulier, quand on dit *frapper à la porte*, on sous-entend qu'il s'agit de frapper dessus — en principe avec la main ou avec un objet — pour se faire ouvrir. Si on dit *frapper la porte*, c'est qu'on la frappe pour autre chose :

> […] le chevalier **frappa la porte** si furieusement de son pied, que les poteaux et les gonds en furent ébranlés. — (Walter Scott, Ivanhoé, Traduction de l’anglais par Alexandre Dumas, 1820)

Comment: Peut-on dire *frapper la porte* dans le sens figuratif, par exemple, "quitter le travail" ou "couper la relation"?